# EVEE: More than one Bloom Color

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine, emission

I like using bloom, but I don't want all emission objects to have the same bloom color.  Is there a way to have different emitting materials to have different bloom colors?

Comment: If you set the bloom color to white, it should be the same as the emission color of the individual materials. I guess the bloom color parameter actually determines which kind of RGB values qualify as bloom.

Comment: Thanks!  I should have noticed that by now!  Post that as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Bloom Color" parameter is actually a filter. It determines to what extent emission colors create a Bloom Effect. If it is set to white, the emission colors will not get filtered and therefor every possible combination of RGB values will create the desired effect with the corresponding color. Basically, the color of the Bloom Effect is the product of "Bloom Color" and emission color.